# Limit involving cube of a power series

Tags: limits, power-series

Let $u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} u_n x^n$ be a power series that has radius of convergence $\rho$, and let $$u^3(x) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} u_n x^n\right)^3 = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} w_n x^n.$$

The question is under which condition $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{w_n}{u_n}=0$?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Have you looked into the Taylor series?